# Use Smart Sensors and still get context variable

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am on Airflow `2.1.4` and I am trying to modify a custom sensor to act as a `Smart Sensor`.

Among other things, to allow a custom sensor to work as a Smart Sensor you need to give it a `poke_context_fields` class variable. This isn't very well documented, but I think it's just a list of the arguments to `__init__` that you want to also be passed to `self.poke()` when that is called by the Smart Sensor DAG/Shard (though I could be wrong).

So I have it like:

```
poke_context_fields = ['myarg1', 'myarg2']
```

I have tested this out, but it seems there is a problem: When the Smart Sensor DAG calls `self.poke()`, it forwards along those arguments as expected, but it does **NOT** give me the regular `context` variable that my `poke` method expects. Unfortunately my code won't work without access to that variable, because it needs certain properties like `context['ds']`, `context['task_instance']`, etc, which would only be available at execution time and not when Python parses the class variable.

I have read the following (https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/11893) but I don't 100% follow. Is there a workaround for this or should I just conclude that I can't use Smart Sensors and should wait to use Deferrable Operators which was released in `2.2.0`?

Comment: I wouldn't put effort on this as Smart Sensors is a deprecated feature https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20151 - You should use Deferrable Operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smart Sensors is/was an experimental feature. Eventually it was decided to deprecate it (see [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/20151)) starting from version 2.3.0 in favor of Deferrable Operators.

To quote the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/deferring.html#smart-sensors):

> Deferrable Operators essentially supersede Smart Sensors, and should
> be preferred for almost all situations.